# How can I get custom unmodified list after changing its list object data in java

Tags: java, android, list, object, arraylist

```
   // Here i have list
```

// How can i prevent a list  to modified  after its object data changed
I want to have a unmodified original  list without  updating it data.
I have also used Arraylist and Collection.unmofifiedList also

How can i get original list i.e.

```
"S Age"- 10
"S Age"- ABC
"S Name "- 30
"S Name "- XYZ

Student s1 = new Student();
s1.setAge(10);
s1.setName("ABC");

Student s2 = new Student();
s2.setAge(30);
s2.setName("XYZ");

ArrayList<Student> al = new ArrayList<Student>();
al.add(s1);
al.add(s2);

// here i am getting list all data
for(int i=0; i<al.size(); i++) {
   System.out.println("F Age " + al.get(i).getAge());
   System.out.println("F Name " + al.get(i).getName());
}

Student s3 = new Student();
s3 = al.get(0);
s3.setAge(50);
s3.setName("Shyam");

for(int i=0;i< al.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("S Age " + al.get(i).getAge());
    System.out.println("S Name " + al.get(i).getName()); 
}
```

Comment: do you want a list that doesnt allow changes or a list of objects that can not be changed???

Comment: yes  I want a list that can not be modified after changing its data using getter setter. @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ

Answer (score 0):

Not without a lot of work around.
Make Student listenable:

```
interface Listener {
    public void changed();
}

class Student {
    private List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addListener(Listener l) { listeners.add(l); }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        //...
        listeners.forEach(Listener::changed);
}
```

and implement List to be a listener that disallows updates upon item changes:

```
class MyList<T> implements List<T>, Listener {
    private List<T> delegate = new ArrayList<T>();
    private boolean editable = true;
    public void changed() { editable = false; }
    public void add(T item) {
        if (editable) {
            delegate.add(item);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException(); // or something
        }
    }
    // also delegate all other List methods in the same way
}
```

I cannot really see the point in doing this though, it does have a "weird design" smell.

Answer (score 0):

you have to different concepts deppending on what you need:

1. you can use an ***unmodifiableList*** meaning that this is a list that you can not modify(you can not add or remove object of that) but you can for sure get those objects on that list an change its state by modifying its fields...
2. you can define the class **Student**  inmutable so you can not change its state after the object is created...

those are 2 different strategies and are not segregative ( you can define one, both or none in your architecture.)

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to make the class(Student class) un-modifiable or immutable so that you don't allow the object to be modified:

Try below one:

```
public final class Student {

    final String name;
    final int age;

    public Student(String name,int age)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.age =age;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s1 = new Student("ABC", 10);

        /*s1.setAge(10);

        s1.setName("ABC");*/


        Student s2 = new Student("XYZ", 30);

        /*s2.setAge(30);

        s2.setName("XYZ");*/

        ArrayList<Student> al = new ArrayList<Student>();

        al.add(s1);

        al.add(s2);

// here i am getting list all data
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("F Age " + al.get(i).getAge());
            System.out.println("F Name " + al.get(i).getName());
        }


        Student s3 = new Student("sss",22);
        s3 = al.get(0);


        // Can't modify because it is not allowed
        /*s3.setAge(50);

        s3.setName("Shyam");*/



        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {

            System.out.println("S Age " + al.get(i).getAge());

            System.out.println("S Name " + al.get(i).getName());

        }
    }


}
```

Steps to create immutable class:

```
•   Class must be declared as final (So that child classes can’t be created)
•   Data members in the class must be declared as final (So that we can’t change the value of it after object creation)
•   A parameterized constructor
•   Getter method for all the variables in it
•   No setters(To not have option to change the value of the instance variable)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

```
//Very nice question and are very complex but i am able to give answer. please use Map istean of array list because arraylist save Object reference

public static void main(String args[]){
        int age = 20;
        String name = "DS";
        Student s1 = new Student();
        s1.setAge(age);
        s1.setName(name);
        Student s2 = new Student();
        s2.setAge(30);
        s2.setName("PS");

        //List<Student> list=new ArrayList<Student>();  
        Map<Integer,Student> list=new HashMap<Integer,Student>();    
        list.put(1,s1);
        list.put(2,s2);

        Student b =null;
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Student> entry:list.entrySet()){    
            int key=entry.getKey();  
            b=entry.getValue();  
            System.out.println(key+" Details:");     
            System.out.println(b.getAge()+" "+b.getName());   
        }    
        Student s3 =    new Student();
        int a = b.getAge();
        String a1 = b.getName();
        a = 100;
        a1= "Shyamji";

        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Student> entry:list.entrySet()){    
            int key=entry.getKey();  
            Student b1=entry.getValue();  
            System.out.println(key+" Details:");   
            System.out.println(b1.getAge()+" "+b1.getName());   
        } 
    }
```

Comment: will it give me unmodified list after changing data